# Javascript class change doesn't change CSS3 gradient in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css

I have a simple div with a CSS3 gradient as background, its original background is declared from a CSS file, where I also declare that this div with another class should have another CSS3 gradient as background. When adding the class to the div with JavaScript the background changes as it should in Firefox, but stays as it was in Chrome. I know the class is added because other styles of the class change as they should.

You can see it in the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLjav/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is just inconsistent.  There needs to be alpha on each of the gradients if you want the same effect in each browser.  This works in chrome.  http://jsfiddle.net/gradbot/vQZtu/

Comment: Hehe, I just tested how it looked on Firefox and than forgot to change the rest, thanks!